# How to build zod schemas where input is unknown whilst requiring defined input?

Tags: typescript, zod

```
interface Purchase {
  invoiceNo?: string
  purchaseDate?: string
  placeOfPurchase?: string
  productId: string
  serialId?: string
  purchasePrice?: number
}
```

I have a Typescript interface like the above where most fields are optional however if a field has been captured when edited on the backend system they should still be required.

So for example if a record has

productId
serialId
purchaseDate

The schema needs to be able to enforce those fields and the defined schema types but allowed the others to be omitted. I should note I need this to be done in a maintainable and reusable manner.

So far I have a schema defined as

```
const schema = z.object({
  invoiceNo: z.string().trim().min(1, { message: 'Invoice No is required' }),
  purchaseDate: z.string().trim().min(1, { message: 'Purchase Date is required' }),
  placeOfPurchase: z.string().trim().min(1, { message: 'Place of Purchase is required' }),
  productId: z.string().trim().min(1, { message: 'Product is required' }),
  serialId: z.string().trim().min(1, { message: 'Serial Number is required' }),
  purchasePrice: z.number().min(1, { message: 'Purchase Price is required' }),
}).strict()
```

Which uses two utility methods

```
export const activeSchemaPick = <S extends ZodObject<any>, E>(schema: S, entity: E) => Object.entries(schema.shape).reduce((acc, [key]) => {
  if (get(entity, key)) {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [key]: true,
    }
  }

  return acc
}, {})

export const activeDefaultValues = <S extends ZodObject<any>, E>(schema: S, entity: E): Partial<E> => Object.keys(schema.shape).reduce((acc, key) => {
  if (get(entity, key)) {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [key]: entity[key as keyof E],
    }
  }

  return acc
}, {})
```

```
const activeSchema = schema.pick(activeSchemaPick(schema, purchase))
  const { register, handleSubmit, getValues, setValue, setError, formState: { errors }, watch } = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(activeSchema),
    defaultValues: activeDefaultValues(activeSchema, purchase),
  })
```

In order to set the fields that are currently required, this seems extremely convoluted however but with my vast searching and research have been unable to find a cleaner solution.

If anyone has any pointers it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any better way to do it,

On a sidenote, you may make all the fields of your schema optional/nullable and instead of doing a `.pick`, use `.required` which from what I understood is more apprioriate in your case as you probably still want to validate others fields in case they are inputed

Comment: Thanks for the reply, slowly thinking this may indeed be the case!

Yeah I think the latter will be dependant on the display of items.